# SQL IN Clause By Giving Just Start and End Numbers Only

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to give an undefined set for the clause of IN ?

Such as:

```
select * from ABC WHERE MY_ID IN (X TO Y)
```

Example: If I give X to 3 and Y to 8 ;

```
select * from ABC WHERE MY_ID IN (3, ... , 8)
```

This should be identical to :

```
select * from ABC WHERE MY_ID IN (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need this

```
select * from ABC WHERE MY_ID between 3 and 8
```

Answer (score 2):

Can try this as well...

```
select * from abc where id >= 3 and id <=8
```

Comment: @Beco I see that you have accepted an answer. `Between` & `<=, >=` has the same `Explain plan`. Please do take a look at this as well. However it's just sugaring up the syntax... ;)

Answer (score 1):

how about `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT * FROM ABC WHERE MY_ID BETWEEN 3 AND 8
```

- [MySQL BETWEEN Operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)